# Why was this question closed as "Not a real question" instead of another close reason?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, not-a-real-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596392/c-the-design-and-evolution-of-c) was closed as *not a real question*. Why are SO reviewers in such a rush to close questions? I was expecting a better reason. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

EDIT: By saying "In a rush" I mean that the people who closed it chose the bad reason, I'm not saying I disagree with closing it.

Comment: It probably falls under the category of "Not Constructive" or "Off Topic" instead.

Comment: I said the reason was not well-chosen. So I'm right, no need to downvote. @Mysticial that's what I would accept as a reason

Comment: Each of the close voters gets to choose a reason. Majority rules. In the event of a tie, the last voter wins. Of course we can't see who voted for which reason. (oh and I didn't downvote)

Comment: Downvotes here often indicate disagreement. You seem to state that your questions should not have been closed that quickly. Some might disagree with that.

Comment: TBH though, when a question has multiple problems with it, people have a tendency to vote NARQ by default. I can see how that happened here.

Comment: You asked that question on SO 30 minutes ago and you don't disagree with that fact that it should have been closed? Then why ask it in the first place? Or were you just hoping to sneak that one through?

Comment: @Bart `I was expecting a better reason`. Why don't you just re-read the question?

Comment: I think it fits under "Not a real question". Also, "Not Constructive", "Off-Topic", and "Too Localized".

Comment: what a smart guy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, the Not a Real Question close reason fits. The question is very broad. I can either answer with, "Why yes, buy the first book" or I could answer with a very complicated review of the book in its entirety, possibly telling you way more than you ever wanted to know.

It's also not clear what problem you're trying to solve. If these questions even were on topic, we'd be able to better guide you to the correct book if we knew more about your goals. Are you an EE or a Computer Scientist, for instance. I'd imagine that would have a greater impact on the answer. For instance, maybe one book was written for electrical engineers using C++ and the other was for Computer Scientists, or maybe device driver writers versus web server developers.

Also, what's your experience level? Are you a developer just getting started, or do you have 10+ years experience and hoping to take your knowledge to the extreme next levels?  Without all of this information, we have to make a lot of, possibly incorrect, assumptions about you and your problem. Thus, your question would be closed as NARQ:

> **not a real question**
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 5):

I would have closed it as "Not Constructive". You're asking for opinions on a book. A shopping recommendation if you will. We simply don't do those.

Comment: Well that's what I mean. I would accept it closed as Not Constructive even though there are lots of questions about books and yet not closed, but seriously, Not real??

Comment: Perhaps some thought "not real" in the sense of, you're not asking a real question on a practical problem you face. And the majority wins on the reason displayed. Still, the question was rightfully closed.

Comment: Not a real question states "It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.". While it is clear. The problem I have is with the mods who choose irrelevant reasons.

Comment: Those are not mods. Those are regular users who have the privilege to vote.

Comment: @cprogcr: Do not assume that because some book questions are not yet closed that book questions are on-topic. What is acceptable on SO has changed over time, and we'll happily close any off-topic questions you can point us to.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a question that is on-topic for SO, no.

It's not a practical programming problem being solved; you are asking people for opinions about what book to buy. That is not a question in accordance with the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

In this case, I'd have voted to close the question as non-constructive myself though.

Comment: That's what I mean by saying "In a rush." They chose reasons blindly.

Answer (score 5):

Although I do agree that [Not A Real Question fits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148407/162704), I think Not Constructive would be a better choice as even if you fixed all the problems jmort253 mentions, the question would still be closed as NC and that would be extremely frustrating.

At the end of the day closed means closed, and the close reason is not more important than the fact the question is closed, but in this particular instance and given that you are a relatively new user I think NC would do a better job conveying what's wrong with the question and would be far more helpful than NARQ, even if NARQ fits perfectly.

Keep in mind that the displayed closed reason is what most of the close voters picked, one or two of the close voters might have picked NC but since NARQ is displayed we know at least three of them picked NARQ.

All that said, I don't think anyone rushed in closing the question, or picking the close reason. Both NC and NARQ fit, and there might even be a case for Off Topic as well, since it's clearly stated in the FAQ that questions that aren't about a practical programming problem are off topic. We can't berate the close voters for picking a close reason that fits, even if there might have been a (slightly) better choice.